# Margin spacing around webparts suddenly disappeared?

Tags: web-part, page-layout, modern-pages, communication-site, layouts

I have a few SharePoint Communication sites. Two days ago I saw that all the vertical spacing (margin) around the webparts I'm using has suddenly disappeared. I don't think I've made any edits recently that could affect this, so wondering if there was a bug or recent update that could have caused this issue?

It can be fixed by adding the spacer webpart into all pages, but I wondered if there was a quicker way? I'm not that familiar with sharepoint code-- the sharepoint basics have been enough for these sites so far.

Usually, we just add the divider webpart for spacing in our columns, but there's no margin above/below it now so all our content is cramped together.

Anyone have any ideas what could have caused this?

Edit: This thread has the same problem, sounds like it's a msft issue- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/151691/did-the-sharepoint-online-page-margins-change.html